# Java - How to propagate the Headers to Spring OpenFeign

Tags: java, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I have a microservice that calls several micro services in cascade, using FeignClient (spring cloud). I want to propagate all the header values between then, without declare one atribute per header value at the feign method.

There is a way to do that? I was not able to find that online.

Sample of the propagation of headers that I have:

```
void doSomething(Long id, 
    @Header("Accept-Language") String language, 
    @Header("Accept") accept, 
    @Header("Authorization") authorization, 
    @Header("Connection") connection, ...)
```

Comment: You can implement `feign.RequestInterceptor`

Comment: @geobreze How do I set the headers from the original request to the next one?

Comment: You can put it to the thread local context. Or you can avoid implementing interceptor using AnnotatedParameterProcessor

Comment: do you have a sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do it with `RequestInterceptor`

```
@Component
class CurrentRequestHeadersInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
  @Override
  public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    if (requestAttributes instanceof ServletRequestAttributes) {
      HttpServletRequest webRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes).getRequest();
      webRequest.getHeaderNames().asIterator()
          .forEachRemaining(h -> template.header(h, webRequest.getHeader(h)));
    }
  }
}
```

As for `AnnotatedParameterProcessor`, I found a way to add only one header from the request, but I don't think this will work for you.

If you prefer explicit header passing, you can use `@RequestHeader` annotation to pass headers as `Map`.

```
@FeignClient(name = "test", url = "localhost:9090")
interface TestClient {
  @RequestMapping("/test")
  void test(@RequestHeader Map<String, List<String>> headers);
}
```

Then you can add `WebRequest` as your controller's method parameter, convert a request to a `Map` of headers and then pass it to the client.